# TryParse is not a member of System.Enum error in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, enums, system

I checked out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1. It should exist.

EDIT:
I tried it on vs2010 (different project, though), and it exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) was added with .Net Framework 4.0.

You can easily tell this by looking at the *Other Versions* drop down menu in the documentation or the version Information:

> **.NET Framework**
>   Supported in: 4.5, 4
>   **.NET Framework Client Profile**
>   Supported in: 4
>   **Portable Class Library**
>   Supported in: Portable Class Library
>   **.NET for Windows Store apps**
>   Supported in: Windows 8

So probably you're using an older .Net Framework version.

Comment: Yeah. I didn't know that until I checked Enum.TryParse for 3.5. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `System Import`?

```
Imports System
```

If you are in Visual Studio 2010, make sure you are targeting **.NET Framework 4.0**

[image]

Comment: I just found out that Enum.TryParse is only in 4 nad 4.5. Dominic Kexel was right. Thanks.

Comment: Nope you can't :( jejeje